# One backbone model in multiple backbone collections

Tags: backbone.js

Is it possible to have one model and add it to multiple collections, while keeping them synchronized?

I'd like to have one item model and then add it to both a player inventory and a store inventory without keeping duplicate models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is totally possible. Just add the model to both collections.

```
m = new Backbone.model({id:1})
c1 = new Backbone.collection(m)
c2 = new Backbone.collection(m)
```

Making any changes to the model will trigger the appropriate events on both `c1` and `c2`